# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'List<RainfallThai>' is not a subtype of type 'RainfallThai?' in type cast)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http, exception

I got this issue when I ran this code like this pic. I try to get API and show it in the emulator and it can show in the debug console but I can't write the code and show it.

[image]

So next to is my code

1. dashboard (dart code)

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_report/RainfallThai.dart';
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

   class DashboardSd extends StatefulWidget {
     const DashboardSd({super.key});

     @override
     State<DashboardSd> createState() => _DashboardSdState();
   }

   class _DashboardSdState extends State<DashboardSd> {
     RainfallThai? _dataFromAPI;
     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       getRainfallThai();
     }

     Future<RainfallThai?> getRainfallThai() async {
       var url = Uri.parse('https://retoolapi.dev/n3bsFG/rainfallthai');
       var response = await http.get(url);
       setState(() {
         _dataFromAPI = rainfallThaiFromJson(response.body) as RainfallThai?;
       });
       return _dataFromAPI;
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
           title: Text(
             "ทดลองดึง API",
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
           ),
         ),
         body: Column(
           children: [
             LinearProgressIndicator(),
             Text(_dataFromAPI?.provinceName ?? 'Loading...')
           ],
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. my api dart code

   ```
   import 'dart:convert';

   List<RainfallThai> rainfallThaiFromJson(String str) => List<RainfallThai>.from(
       json.decode(str).map((x) => RainfallThai.fromJson(x)));

   String rainfallThaiToJson(List<RainfallThai> data) =>
       json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

   class RainfallThai {
     int? id;
     Date? date;
     String? year;
     String? month;
     Region? region;
     String? avgRain;
     String? maxRain;
     String? minRain;
     MonthTh? monthTh;
     String? provinceId;
     String? provinceName;
     String? provinceName2;

     RainfallThai({
       this.id,
       this.date,
       this.year,
       this.month,
       this.region,
       this.avgRain,
       this.maxRain,
       this.minRain,
       this.monthTh,
       this.provinceId,
       this.provinceName,
       this.provinceName2,
     });

     factory RainfallThai.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RainfallThai(
           id: json["id"],
           date: dateValues.map[json["Date"]]!,
           year: json["Year"],
           month: json["Month"],
           region: regionValues.map[json["region"]]!,
           avgRain: json["AvgRain"],
           maxRain: json["MaxRain"],
           minRain: json["MinRain"],
           monthTh: monthThValues.map[json["Month_TH"]]!,
           provinceId: json["ProvinceID"],
           provinceName: json["ProvinceName"],
           provinceName2: json["ProvinceName 2"],
         );

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
           "id": id,
           "Date": dateValues.reverse[date],
           "Year": year,
           "Month": month,
           "region": regionValues.reverse[region],
           "AvgRain": avgRain,
           "MaxRain": maxRain,
           "MinRain": minRain,
           "Month_TH": monthThValues.reverse[monthTh],
           "ProvinceID": provinceId,
           "ProvinceName": provinceName,
           "ProvinceName 2": provinceName2,
         };
   }

   enum Date { THE_1118, THE_1218 }

   final dateValues =
       EnumValues({"1/1/18": Date.THE_1118, "1/2/18": Date.THE_1218});

   enum MonthTh { EMPTY, MONTH_TH }

   final monthThValues =
       EnumValues({"มกราคม": MonthTh.EMPTY, "กุมภาพันธ์ ": MonthTh.MONTH_TH});

   enum Region { EMPTY, FLUFFY, PURPLE, REGION, STICKY, TENTACLED }

   final regionValues = EnumValues({
     "กลาง": Region.EMPTY,
     "เหนือ": Region.FLUFFY,
     "ตะวันออกเฉียงเหนือ": Region.PURPLE,
     "ตะวันออก": Region.REGION,
     "ใต้": Region.STICKY,
     "ตะวันตก": Region.TENTACLED
   });

   class EnumValues<T> {
     Map<String, T> map;
     late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

     EnumValues(this.map);

     Map<T, String> get reverse {
       reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
       return reverseMap;
     }
   }
   ```

I try to solve including who got this same issue but it's not work to me

Answer (score 0):

When you created the method `rainfallThaiFromJson(String str)` you set a return type of `List<RainfallThai>`, but when you call it in the following part

```
setState(() {
      _dataFromAPI = rainfallThaiFromJson(response.body) as RainfallThai?;
    });
```

you're trying to convert it in a `RainfallThai?` object. So you need to either cast the type to be `List<RainfallThai?>` or you have to change `rainfallThaiFromJson` in a way that returns you a `RainfallThai` object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where can I change it?

Comment: In the 
`
setState(() {
      _dataFromAPI = rainfallThaiFromJson(response.body) as RainfallThai?;
    });
`
you can write instead
`
setState(() {
      _dataFromAPI = rainfallThaiFromJson(response.body) as List<RainfallThai?>;
    });
`

Comment: Ok , I will try it and give the result later, so thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: It doesn’t worked , so I already change with the new methods.Thanks so much :).